# Passing properties to a custom control using xp:include

Tags: xpages

When using an Include Page  to dynamically load a custom control onto an XPage, is there a way to pass custom property values to the custom control as part of the include?

Comment: How do you load your CCs? Can you add a code snippet?

Comment: <xp:include id="detailControl"    loaded="${javascript:SessionBean.getViewDetailControl()}">
<xp:this.pageName><![CDATA[${SessionBean.viewDetailControl}]]></xp:this.pageName>
</xp:include>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter, the include page doesn't load a custom control but another XPage. Pages don't have properties. However... the page becomes part of the component tree, so you have access to its contained controls using `getComponent("thecomponent").getParameterMap` (Off my head, might be called slightly different)

Does that help?

Comment: Hi Stefan. I beg to differ... the xp:include control can be used to include custom controls. I have many examples of using this to great effect. It is because of this that I need to find a way to pass property values. Perhaps IBM did not intend it be used this way which is why the passing of property values there does not seem to be an obvious way to do this. But I will certainly use your suggestion to see if I can get that to work and post the answer here.

Comment: Yep. Include is for PAGE inclusion. Controls and pages live on the same level, so an inclusion of a control might work (that feature could be treated as a bug and disappear!) but since it is a page mechanism no parameters are evaluated. The map might be your best guess

Comment: With reluctance I am going to accept your answer Stefan ;)... I hate accepting something can't be done!!