# Pass parameters to a computed custom control

Tags: xpages

I'm using the xp:include tag for displaying custom controls according business rules.

I configured my custom controls with parameters (the custom prperties) that I used through the compositeData syntax.

My question is :
How can I declare the computed xpages for passing arguments to my custom control ?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15325595/2065611 = you can't pass parameters.

Comment: Instead of xp:include you could dynamically add the custom control to your XPage. Here is an example how to do this: https://github.com/hasselbach/domino-ccinjector

Answer (score 1):

Switch control or Dynamic Content Control may be a better option to choose. The difference is Switch control loads all facets into the component tree, Dynamic Content Control only loads the current facet to be displayed. So if they're specific to different parts in the business process, Dynamic Content Control may be more suitable.

Alternatively, use different XPages for different stages in the business process. With XPages links from views can be computed to go to a specific XPage rather than a single one defined for the form.